# How do I wrap a call to sudo in Python3 and capture any output and errors?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, sudo, popen

Because of the changes in bytes vs string handling in Python3 the older solutions to similar questions are hard to use.

So I'm posting this just to provide a working example.

The generic answer is still, use the *[subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess%20popen#subprocess.Popen)* functionality with [subprocess.PIPE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess%20pipe#subprocess.PIPE) objects, and use the ***sudo -S*** (**--stdin**) command line, to sanely feed the password into the running **sudo** command without doing psuedo-terminal handling.

The wrinkle is that the password has to be encoded as Python **bytes** and any captured output and error messages must be encoded back into Python strings.

Comment: I guess there are **text=** and **encoding=** options to *subprocess.Popen()* in newer versions of Python3 ... so those ***might*** be useful for some situations when using versions newer than 3.6 or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

So, without further ado, here's one working solution:

```
#!python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from getpass import getpass
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from shlex import split as shplit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = 'sudo -S id'
    response = getpass()
    pw = bytes(response+'\r\n', 'ascii')
    proc = Popen(shplit(cmd), stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

    out = err = None  # In case of timeout
    out, err = proc.communicate(input=pw, timeout=None)

    out = str(out,'ascii')
    err = str(err,'ascii')

    if err.startswith('Password:'):
        err = err[len('Password:'):]
    if err:
        print('Errors: ', err)
        print()
    if out:
        print('Output: \n', out)
    results = proc.poll()
    errorcode = proc.returncode
    print('Return code: ', errorcode)
    sys.exit(errorcode)
```

Obviously most of this is in the wrapping.  Most real code would get getting the password and the command for **sudo** to execute via some other means; and the post-processing of the output and error messages would normally be different.  (Actually this example does a poor job of filtering **sudo**'s prompt for your password out of the final output; fixing that's left as an exercise to the reader).

Of course this uses [shlex.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html?highlight=shlex%20split#shlex.split) as the safer approach than **shell=True**.